# IBM WAS sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols() issue

Tags: websphere, tls1.2, okhttp, sslhandshakeexception, jsse

We have a single installation of `WAS(8.5.5.10)`, with multiple clusters(JVMs). We enabled `TLS1.2` on one of the JVMs, (say JVM1). But when I run the code `sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols()`, it gives me `supported protocols=[TLSv1]`, which is V 1.0. My application runs on `Java 1.7`.

When I check in Security > SSL certificate and key management, and under Related Items, click SSL configurations. ( such as CellDefaultSSLsetting , NodedefaultSSLsetting and any other SSLConfig), it shows 'TLS' as the protocol, under QoP settings.

But when I check in SSL certificate and key management > Manage endpoint security configurations > jvm1_cluster, it shows 'TLS1.2' as SSL configuration.

From IBM forums, I came to understand that it is possible to enable TLSV1.2 at only one cluster. and need to use jssehelper to specify an outbound ssl configuration.

Tried following the link on how to programmatically specifying an outbound SSL configuration using JSSEHelper API. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_ssloutconfiguseJSSE.html

but I still could not get it to work. When I print the properties, I can see protocol as TLSV1.2 (com.ibm.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2). Application uses `com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl` for ssl socket provider.

To give you some background, am trying to connect to APNS using okhttp3 library. Am adding these properties, at the place where I create the socket connection. And after the socket is created, when I do `sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols()`, it gives me `supported protocols=[TLSv1]`, which is V 1.0.

Since it tries to connect via TLS1, it gives `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`, when trying to establish connection to APNS. I have the certificate added to was store already and the firewall rules are in place as well, to allow the connection.

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:21)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.b(qc.java:465)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:451)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:353)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:800)
```

Pls guide me on how to fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I believe okhttp3 create it's own SSLContext instance.  So it will not pick up a WebSphere SSLContext by default nor will the programmatic SSL link you reference work.   You can call the JSSEHelper to get the properties make the TLSv1.2 change you are doing then call the JSSEHelper getSSLSSLSocketFactory() passing in those modified properties.  Then with the socket factory you get back assign it to okhttp builder.

Comment: @Alaine - Can you pls share some code sample, for me to understand it better. As I mentioned, I followed the link and used option 1, com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper jsseHelper  = com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper.getInstance();try 
{  String alias = "MyNodealias";
  // As specified in the WebSphere SSL configuration  Properties
 sslProps = jsseHelper.getProperties(alias); }
 catch (com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException e)
 {  e.printStackTrace();   // handle exception } .

Comment: @Alaine  - contd from earlier.. and when I print those properties, I can see com.ibm.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2.  and then I do jsseHelper.setSSLPropertiesOnThread(sslProps); So do you mean, after I set these properties to jsseHelper, to get SSLSocketFactory from jsse itself and then use the same to create the okhttp builder? I feel, some example will help me follow it better. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Setting on the properties on the thread will not work with okhttp.    Since the configuration you are getting contains TLSv1.2 already then  you can call SSLSocketFactory factory = jsseHelper.getSSLSocketFactory(MyNodealias, null, null).  You will get a socket factory created with the properties in MyNodealias.   Then you can set that factory on the okhttp builder.   From reading okHttp docs it seems you should be able to do something like  OkHttpClient.Builder.sslSocketFactory(factory).

Comment: @Alaine - thanks. I will try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Alaine - After the changes, am running into issue "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.platform.JdkWithJettyBootPlatform@2d7d8796, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl". Am trying to google a fix for it. just wanted to update you.

Comment: @Alaine - Can you pls help here? Am not able to find a fix for it. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know much about okhttp and it does not seem to handle IBMJRE's socket factory.  There is some information here https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2427.   I assumed all it would work with any java socket factory.   It seems they suggest you using the method OkHttpClient.Builder.sslSocketFactory(factory, trustmanager).

Comment: @Alaine  - I tried setting to set TLSV1,1.1 as disabled programatically as below.
     Security.setProperty("com.ibm.websphere.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1");

But I still get a SSL handshake exception. It does show TLSV1.2 as enabled protocol though, when I do sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols().

 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:21)
   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.b(qc.java:465)
   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:451)
   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)

Comment: The properties most likely have to be done early in the process before getting used.   You must be running on a level of the JDK where the outbound default is TLSv1.   You can try overriding the default protocol, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/overrideSSLprotocol.html.   Only thing is you really need to set it on the jvm properties on WebSphere not programmatically.    You can find instructions here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417365#howto.

Comment: @Alaine - I will try this but as I mentioned, after setting the disabled protocols property, It shows TLSV1.2 as enabled protocol, when I do sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols().

Comment: I misunderstood, my current suggestion will likely not get you anything different.   I don't know why your are recieving the error.  The error sems to be with the server side of the communication, does it have any information on why it fails?  You can try running with jsse trace to see if any more meaningful information can be found.

Comment: @Alaine - sorry for getting back late. had some env issues. we turned on the ssl trace and here are the logs. SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
SystemOut     O WebContainer : 0, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
Am not sure why. Can you pls help me with this?

Comment: @Alaine - Am not able to post the complete trace here. Am trying to see how to move this to chat, so that I can share complete trace to you.

Comment: Sorry been out for a while.  The partial message you provided suggest a mismatch in protocol.  But I really need full trace to see.  If you open a pmr it can be investigated there.